# How to fix hover on transparent photo

Tags: html, css, hover

Here is my problem im creating this map that when you hover on the states it switches the background position so that picture/state changes to a dark color but if i hover over california it selects nevada and thats whats the problem how can i adjust the hover to just the single states.

Heres the photo:
http://ge.tt/9HvFiYA1/v/0
the botom left is california and the bottom right is nevada i hover under nevada and it still highlights nevada and not california.

html:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
        <a href="" id="washington"></a>
        <a href="" id="oregon"></a>
        <a href="" id="california"></a>
        <a href="" id="nevada"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#contentwrap {
    min-width: 1150px;
    max-width: 1150px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0px solid #bdbebe;
    top: -52px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#washington{
    background-image: url(washington.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    height: 92px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 92px;
    left: 122px;
    display: block;
}
#washington:hover {
    background-position: -131px 0;
}
#oregon{
    background-image: url(oregon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 154px;
    height: 126px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 58px;
    left: 88px;
    display: block;
}
#oregon:hover {
    background-position: -162px 0;
}
#california{
    background-image: url(california.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 154px;
    height: 262px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 71px;
    display: block;
}
#california:hover {
    background-position: -155px 0;
}
#nevada{
    background-image: url(nevada.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 155px;
    height: 186px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -215px;
    left: 137px;
    display: block;
}
#nevada:hover {
    background-position: -171px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated your situation is js-fiddle.  Instead of using the pictures, though, I used colors.  The bounding boxes are much more visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy7Fp/

As you can see, your boxes overlap.  You would have to come up with some way to deal with this, or perhaps utilize an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) so that you can just use one large image

Changes to your css to see the bounding box better:

```
contentwrap {
    min-width: 1150px;
    max-width: 1150px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0px solid #bdbebe;
    top: -52px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#washington{
    background-color:green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    height: 92px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 92px;
    left: 122px;
    display: block;
}
#washington:hover {
    background-position: -131px 0;
}
#oregon{
    background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 154px;
    height: 126px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 58px;
    left: 88px;
    display: block;
}
#oregon:hover {
    background-position: -162px 0;
}
#california{
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 154px;
    height: 262px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 71px;
    display: block;
}
#california:hover {
    background-position: -155px 0;
}
#nevada{
    background-color:orange;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 155px;
    height: 186px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -215px;
    left: 137px;
    display: block;
}
#nevada:hover {
    background-position: -171px 0;
}
```

### Here's an actual working solution:

I went ahead and setup the image map method for you using the image you provided.  You can see it in action, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N3p5W/).

**HTML**

```
<img id="states" src="http://archive.dadelamkins.com/StackExchange/20697449/Normal%20Map.png" usemap="#states" />

<map name="states">
    <area shape="poly" coords="255,70,169,49,169,73,133,54,133,90,130,104,143,109,147,111,147,115,147,118,147,123,158,129,164,126,178,132,210,134,242,139,248,105" onmouseover="flip('http://archive.dadelamkins.com/StackExchange/20697449/Washington.png')" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="133,109,99,183,94,200,218,234,232,184,229,180,229,173,246,151,244,144,234,141,220,137,187,135,175,135,164,129,149,129,144,126,146,113,140,109" onmouseover="flip('http://archive.dadelamkins.com/StackExchange/20697449/Oregon.png')" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="274,247,246,388,235,384,230,406,155,293,171,224" onmouseover="flip('http://archive.dadelamkins.com/StackExchange/20697449/Nevada.png')" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="167,223,98,204,96,220,89,233,84,239,87,250,90,259,83,274,97,304,104,300,104,318,99,314,97,325,104,330,102,342,114,381,114,391,117,398,131,402,141,414,148,415,152,421,156,426,168,439,170,454,218,463,224,457,220,458,219,448,232,430,232,422,226,407,152,294,160,256" onmouseover="flip('http://archive.dadelamkins.com/StackExchange/20697449/California.png')" href="#" />
</map>
```

**Javascript**

```
flip = function(img) {
    document.getElementById("states").src = img;
}
```

Comment: how would you approach a step like this where you have to make a map with seperate states?

Comment: in other words every state has to be next to each other and it has to be hoverable

Comment: @user2865738 Use an image map and then have the replacement images be the whole picture with only the hovered state darkened, or what have you.

Comment: @user2865738 I've made an edit to my post which now includes a working solution using image-maps.

Comment: best answer although im not gonna go with it because i would have to do all the cordinates for every state and that too much work but i will need it in the future lol thanks man, merry christmas

Comment: @user2865738 Just on a side note, I managed to do it all fairly easy and in just a few minutes using GIMP.  GIMP has a built in tool for generating image maps.